# React useSelector Value Not Changed Inside Async Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-redux, httprequest

I want to use the useSelector state to send the new bugs state to a server inside an async function, but the value does not change. What am I doing wrong?

1. When submitting a form I want to update the bugs state and send it to the server
2. Inside an async function I do dispatch(updateBugs(newBug)) and the state is updated so this works
3. I get the state with const { bugs } = useSelector((state) => state.bugs); and the state seems to be updated
4. When I send the updated bugs list with await sendUpdatedBugsToServer(bugs); inside the async function, the bugs state seems to be the old one.

■bug-actions.js

```
export const sendUpdatedBugsToServer = (newBugsList) => {
  const storeData = async (newBugsList) => {
    
    const response = await fetch(`${databaseURL}/bugs.json`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(newBugsList),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('cannot store new bug');
    }
  };

  try {
    storeData(newBugsList);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
};
```

■UpdateBugs.js

```
const EditBug = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { bugs } = useSelector((state) => state.bugs);  //new bug state reflected here

  const submitUpdatedBugs = async () => {
    const newBug = {
      title: enteredTitle,
      details: enteredDetails,
      steps: enteredSteps,
      version: enteredVersion,
      priority: enteredPriority,
      assigned: enteredAssigned,
      creator: enteredCreator,
      id: enteredId,
    };
    await dispatch(updateBugs(newBug));  //update bugs state
    await sendUpdatedBugsToServer(bugs);  //new bug state not reflected here
  }
};

const submitUpdatedBugHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  submitUpdatedBugs();
};
```

Comment: `dispatch` here is not an async function, so `await`ing it has no effect. And `bugs` is a closure variable, so its value is not going to suddenly change after the fact. I'm not sure what is the best approach here, but you may want to consider adding a store action (using middleware) that performs the server request using the latest state.

Comment: As @JLRishe said, you can't await your action creator. Usually, we can use redux-thunk middleware and do the async operation like API call. But looks like you are doing an optimistic update. In that case, you may use useEffect with bugs as param and call your API call there. Bad design but will work.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I didn't know await dispatch doesn't do anything...
I took a different approach and somehow worked well! Instead of replacing all bugs in the server, I decided to replace only the specified bug.

1. Changed the database URL to a specific bug and used PUT method to replace only that bug
2. In UpdateBugs.js, I searched for the matching bug using params